# Indefinite integration of a function with a trigonometric function raised to a high power

Tags: indefinite-integrals

I need to integrate indefinitely the expression

$$      \frac{\csc^{2}x - 2017}{\cos^{2017}x}  $$

I am unable to handle this high power of $\cos(x)$ . A hint would be useful for me.

Comment: By "cosec", do you mean the cosecant function, more commonly abbreviated "csc"?

Comment: Yes , and I have edited the question

Comment: Should I delete the question? I have got my answer. Thanks @lab

Comment: Might as well, I don't really see much a random person could get out of this question otherwise.

Comment: Do you mean that the question is of a good difficulty? If yes, thanks 

Comment: I mean that people are just going to see a link to the question that has basically the same method and answer. It's no doubt a nontrivial problem, but this page basically serves as saying "hey your answer is on this other page instead."